# Page number of pdf inside uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image]In my app i am using `UIWebView` for displaying the pdf from an External url.  Its get loaded perfectly.  While scrolling page number is displayed inside a box. Is there any way to get the page number in code?

Comment: It is possible if you use core graphics to render pdf but with webview you are at the mercy of some intelligent javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next code:

```
- (int)getActualPage
{
    float scrollViewHeight = self.webView.frame.size.height;
    float pageOffset = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    return ((int)pageOffset / (int)scrollViewHeight)+1;
}
```

This code gives you the page number of the document when you see the full page on the `UIScrollView`. If you want to get the same page number that the `UIWebView` gives you, just change the final operation. I think that using the module you can get what you want. I know it's not the perfect solution but it's the best I got.

Comment: This works fine, you just need to take account of the current Zoom level before calculating the pages. I use this -      self.pageNumber = ceilf(((verticalContentOffset + self.halfScreenHeight) / self.pageHeight)/self.zoomScale);